# (Windows Server 2012 R2) Is it possible to split a failover cluster into 2 new clusters by expanding and splitting the existing cluster?

Tags: cluster, failover, failovercluster, windows-cluster, ravendb

Say you have an existing application cluster using Windows Failover Clustering - something perhaps like this:

---

Roles:

- File Share
- Services
- RavenDB

  - ClusterDisk
  - Service
  - ServerName (ravendb.mydomain)

Nodes - 2

---

Now, I want to take those RavenDB resources and move them to it's own failover cluster.

There are two lines of thought for us here:

1. We could create the new cluster separately, get RavenDB up and running. Then pull our systems down to migrate the data and DNS Name to the new cluster. For a production system, this would mean a bit of downtime.

OR

2. We could get RavenDB up and running on our new servers, then add them as nodes to the existing cluster. Then we would limit the Raven cluster group to the new servers.

After this point, are we able to "split" off these nodes into a new, separate cluster? Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIR, you can't split the cluster, the best way is to create new one and migrate DB to a new cluster with little downtime window.